# Protect the code by including headers in static library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, static-libraries

I've created a static library for interaction with a web service. 
When I use a static library, I need to include the compiled library and the header files in the project.  Is there a way to protect the header code or include it in the compiled library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler needs the header files when you (or someone else) uses your library in a project. The header files cannot be included in the library file or hidden somewhere else.

You don't have to include the headers in distributed executables (apps).